# Trackball-like controls in Three.js

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I have been making a 3D game for quite a bit and I stopped on a complex problem with the controls. I use custom pointerlock controls and I want the rotation to behave like three.js `TrackballControls`.

My code:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    camera.position.x = (Math.sin(euler.y) - Math.sin(euler.x)) * zoomValue + lastPlayerX;
    camera.position.z = (Math.cos(euler.y) - Math.sin(euler.x)) * zoomValue + lastPlayerZ;
    camera.position.y = -Math.sin(euler.x) * zoomValue + lastPlayerY;
    composer.render();
}
animate();
```

`lastPlayerX`, `lastPlayerY` and `lastPlayerZ` are the player position axes (which is the target the camera has to "orbit" around), `euler` is a `THREE.Euler` representing the camera rotation and `zoomValue` is how far the camera has to zoom out.

The main riddle is the calculation method, so what would I have to do to make the camera orbit around the player? (around the X and Y axis only).

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out:

The correct formula was

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    camera.position.x = Math.sin(euler.y) * Math.sin(euler.x + Math.PI / 2) * zoomValue + lastPlayerX;
    camera.position.z = Math.cos(euler.y) * Math.sin(euler.x + Math.PI / 2) * zoomValue + lastPlayerZ;
    camera.position.y = -Math.sin(euler.x) * zoomValue + lastPlayerY;
    composer.render();
}
animate();
```

I hope this helps anyone!